# IIS7.5 periodically stops serving static files

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5

I have a website with an index.html file (that contains an html/javascript application) that leverages a json rest api(asp.net webapi in the same website) for data. Periodically, IIS will start returning 500 errors when someone tries to hit the root of the site (index.html).

Oddly enough, the api is still 100% responsive to requests from fiddler while IIS refuses to serve that index file.

Any ideas as to what would cause this strange behavior? It would make sense if the whole site would become un-responsive but I just can't see why iis would suddenly stop serving index.html. Thoughts?

Comment: Is there anything in the event log?

Comment: @jao Unfortunately, there isn't anything helpful there... Since this happened I have just had to restart the website and it seems to be more stable now... Not exactly re-assuring as I have no idea what caused/solved the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate your issue please, 1) Which version of IIS is you are using? What is the server OS? 2) Do you have multiple websites hosted on this server? If yes, I have you seen the same issue for another sites as well? 3) Please can you copy the exact error message and past it here? The error 500 can be because of various issues. 4) Please check if the below article is relevant to your issue, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311766 5) Please get the IIS log files and paste it here. The location of logs files is 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC1 '. Also let me know the date and time th